# ATX mainboard always on

Tags: power, atx, apm

I am moving my 6x86 system into an ATX case from an AT case. The mainboard is Amptron PM9800 supporting both AT and ATX power supply.

As soon as I apply power on the power supply, the system turns on and starts booting normally. What do I need to do to make it stay off until the power switch is pushed?
No pins like PWR or RST are currently connected, only ATX power.

Edit: after first start-up, everything is fine: the PC can sleep, wake-up, turn off properly then turn on again.

What might be interesting is that it takes a few seconds to "forget" about being off after power loss. If I unplug and then plug back quickly, it remains off.

Comment: Have you read the manual if it contains something about it? Or the BIOS settings? Sometimes you can choose what happens when mains power is applied, useful for computers that need to automatically turn back on after a power outage.

Comment: Check your bios settings.

Comment: I have looked at the manual and bios, too. No such setting. The closest thing is "APM enable/disable" but it does not change the behaviour. Maybe ATX support is not complete on this board or bios? After all, it is not of ATX form factor.

Comment: @Dercsár What about other settings such as wake on modem, wake on LAN, or wake on RTC? Maybe they always trigger it on for some reason? Do you have the latest BIOS version? Have you cleared the CMOS settings by removing the battery or shorting a jumper?

Comment: What happens when you shut down a system that supports APM or ACPI (like Windows 95)? Does the power supply turn off, or does it stay powered on?

Comment: @MichaelKarcher When turned off (S0 if I remember correctly), power supply is off. I am not sure exactly how ATX/APM/ACPI come together.

Comment: I remember the behavior wasn't entirely unusual. In the early days of ATX, some of my PCs would boot up as soon as you plugged them in, even without pressing the power button. Once connected to power, it could be turned on and off. Unplugging/reconnecting the power also caused the PC to boot without pressing the power button. While I can't remember the brand of the motherboard, it was a very common brand. Your motherboard may retain this ATX-like behavior even when connected to an AT power supply

Comment: @Tommylee2k According to my copy of The Winn L. Rosch Hardware Bible, 5e, Soft On/Off was introduced with ACPI in December 1996, the year after Intel introduced ATX, so I'd be surprised to see AT power supplies supporting soft off... and, if the PSU is directly and physically switched, I don't see how the motherboard could "retain this ATX-like behaviour" in any meaningful sense. It's more that the motherboard is retaining a semblance of AT-like behaviour when connected to the ATX PSU, in that when power is initially supplied, it always turns on.

Comment: The BIOS option you're looking to turn off is usually something involving "Power Failure"

Comment: @ssokolow yea, you're completely right. forget that last sentence, it was nonsense :D

Comment: Granted, I also made a slight mistake in that I should have said "introduced *for desktop mainboards*", since soft on/off for laptops and APM certainly predate ACPI.